# When do I use join method in multiprocessing module?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm learning about the multiprocessing module. I've found these examples in the documentation at python.org:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Here they use join to finish the process.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

def f(l, i):
    l.acquire()
    try:
        print('hello world', i)
    finally:
        l.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()

    for num in range(10):
        Process(target=f, args=(lock, num)).start()
```

But they don't use it in this case. I also read this:

> Remember also that non-daemonic processes will be joined automatically.

That explains the second example. So why should I use join in the first one? Must I do that because the Process is in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `join()` when you want to wait for any subprocess to finish, e.g. if your main program wants to do something based on the results of the workers.  You should also call `join()` if your main process is long running and creates subprocess frequently.  Otherwise, the ones you didn't join will accumulate as "zombie processes".

In general, whenever the thread of execution of your main process reaches a point where waiting for the subprocesses doesn't hurt, just do so.  It's a bit like closing a file -- it's not strictly necessary, since all files will be implicitly closed on exit, but it is good practice, since it saves resources.